# How to print a rdlc report as duplex with some pages always on the front side?

Tags: pdf, printing, report, rdlc

Is there any way to make sure that a page from a rdlc report will always be printed on the front side of a duplex?

I am creating the rdlc dynamicaly, I tried with pagebreaks but I don't want to have blank pages in the pdf file.

Comment: Have you found a solution for this? I'm with the same problem

Comment: yes. I used keeptogether